# Is there any tool to generate uml diagrams for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, uml

I want to know whether any tool is available to generate uml diagrams based on the ruby class files.

My Rails version: 2.3.14
Ruby version: 1.9.3p547

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Google using `gem rails uml`...

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Rails_Class_Diagrams